# When the expression $p^2 - pq + q^2$ is divisible by 3?

Tags: number-theory, divisibility

Let $p$ and $q$ be integers in a fixed range $[0, N]$. Is there an easy way to say when $p^2 - pq + q^2$ is divisible by 3? More or less, I need to find the probability that, if $q$ and $p$ are picked randomly from the set above, the expression is divisible by 3. Could you please help me?

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1537964/show-p-prime-s-t-p-not-equiv-1-mod-3-is-represented-by-the-binary-quadrat

Answer (score 11, accepted):

$p^2 - pq + q^2 = (p+q)^2 - 3pq$
Then we conclude that if and only if $p+q$ is divisible by 3, the expression is divisible by 3

Comment: If *and only if*, in fact.

Comment: Well, i think my statement is true. If it was stated in following way, you might be right: “The expression is divisible by 3 if and only if ...” Anyway I'm not logic expert:)

Comment: Little more thought and i see that my statement is not complete. Your right...